# change data of a file which contain an array using node

Tags: node.js

I have created a file called `config.js` which looks like below:

```
const config = {
    staticFiles:{
        name:[
            './',
            './index.html',
            './script.js',
            './icon.jpg'
        ]
    },
    outputFolderName: "D:\\DemoApp",
    sourceApplicationParentPath: "D:\\DemoApp\\"
};
```

Now I am reading list of files from `sourceApplicationParentPath` folder using node and have to update `staticFiles` array of above file. I am not sure how should I do it. Can someone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config.js

```
const config = {

staticFiles:{
        name:[
            './',
    './index.html',
    './script.js',
    './icon.jpg'
]
    },

    outputFolderName: "D:\\DemoApp",
    sourceApplicationParentPath: "D:\\DemoApp\\"
};

exports.config = config;
```

code for the file from where you want to change the data

```
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var config = require('./config.js')

//path of directory 
var directoryPath = "D:\\DemoApp\\"

var data = config.config;

//passsing directoryPath and callback function
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    //handling error
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    } 

var dataToUpdate = data.staticFiles.name;

    //listing all files using forEach
    files.forEach(function (file) {

        // Do whatever you want to do with the file
        console.log(file)

        dataToUpdate.push(file)

    });

data.staticFiles.name = dataToUpdate;

var value = 'const config = ' + JSON.stringify(data) + ';' + '\n' + 'exports.config = config';

fs.writeFile('./config.js',value, er => {
      if(er){
        throw er;
      }
      else{console.log('success')}          
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Sanjay but it's not reading file, I've already written this code but I am not able to update staticFiles array in config.js file . It means if we are reading file let us x.js, y.js, j.js using your code then our config.js should be look like:

staticFiles:{
        name:[
            './',
    './index.html',
    './script.js',
    './icon.jpg',
x.js,
y.js,
z.js
]

Comment: I have edited the answer.I checked this and it works.please try and let me know

Answer (score 1):

**config.js**

```
const config = {
    staticFiles: {
        name: ['./',
            './index.html',
            './script.js',
            './icon.jpg',
        ]
    },
    outputFolderName: 'D:\\DemoApp',
    sourceApplicationParentPath: 'D:\\DemoApp'
};

module.exports = config;
```

**index.js**

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    config = require('./config'),
    util = require('util');

fs.readdir(config.sourceApplicationParentPath, function(err, files) {


if (err) console.log(err.message);

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    if (config.staticFiles.name.indexOf(`./${files[i]}`) == -1) {

        config.staticFiles.name.push('./' + files[i]);
    }

    if (i == (files.length - 1)) {

        var buffer = `const config =  \n ${util.inspect(config, false, 2, false)};  \n module.exports = config;`;

        fs.writeFile('./config.js', buffer, function(err) {
            err || console.log('Data replaced \n');

        })

    }


}

});
```

The Above code is tested and working fine.

You can add or change the object or an array or value in config.js without duplicate entry.